# My REST API (using Jersey) cannot find a message body writer (for JSON) for a persisted entity (using OpenJPA).

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, openjpa

I am implementing a REST API on a server which accesses a MySql database. The database is accessed using JDBC/OpenJPA. There are several objects models which are annotated with both OpenJPA annotations (@Id, @Column, etc.) and object-XML binding annotations (@XmlRootElement, @XmlElement, etc.). I am using Jersey for the REST API. The problem is that when try to access something like "myapp/.../users/admin" I get an error which says there is message body writer for `Java class org.apache.openjpa.enhance.com$stod$models$User$pcsubclass, and Java type class com.stod.models.User, and MIME media type application/json was not found` when "myapp/.../users/admin" reads off the database. But when I rewrite the function for "myapp/.../users/admin" to make a new `com.stod.models.User` object (without persisting to the database first), everything works as expected. Why?

Here are the relevant code snippets.

`User.class`:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@Entity(name = "USER")
public class User implements Base, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8015178615266549325L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USERNAME", nullable = false, length = 128, unique = true, updatable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORDHASH", nullable = false, length = 128, unique = false, updatable = true)
    private String passwordHash;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST })
    private Collection<Circle> circlesOwned;
    @XmlElement
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public String getPasswordHash() {
        return passwordHash;
    }

    public void setPasswordHash(String password) {
        this.passwordHash = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(password);
    }

    @XmlElement
    public Collection<Circle> getCirclesOwned() {
        return circlesOwned;
    }

    public void setCirclesOwned(Collection<Circle> circlesOwned) {
        this.circlesOwned = circlesOwned;
    }
    //...
}
```

`Circle.class`:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "circle")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@Entity(name = "CIRCLE")
public class Circle implements Base, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4653602066511306690L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "CIRCLEID")
    @XmlElement
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 128, unique = false, updatable = true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST })
    @XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="circlesOwned")
    private User owner;
}
```

`Service.class`:

```
@Path("/service")
public class Service {
    static HighLogicHelper lHelper = null;

    static {
        if (lHelper == null) {
            try {
                lHelper = new HighLogicHelper();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/echo/{message}")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String echo(@PathParam("message") String message) {
        return message + " is your message";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/users/{username}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public User getUser(@PathParam("username") String username) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(username);
        user = (User) lHelper.findUser(user); //lHelper finds the user by username and returns the persisted object off the database


        User user2 = new User();
        user2.setUsername(user.getUsername());
        user2.setCirclesOwned(user.getCirclesOwned());
        //NOTE! returning user2 works just fine (because user2 wasn't previously persisted?)
        return user;
    }
}
```

`web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>com.vogella.jersey.first</display-name>
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.stod.server</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Full `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stod.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>stod-server</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>stod-server</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.stod.models</groupId>
            <artifactId>stod-models</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId> <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId> 
            <version>2.0.0.GA</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId> 
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId> <version>1.1.GA</version> 
            </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <path>/stod</path>
                    <update>true</update>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Relevant stack trace:

```
Oct 20, 2014 11:30:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/stod.war
Oct 20, 2014 11:30:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:com:sun:jersey:api:view is already defined
Oct 20, 2014 11:30:51 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.stod.server
Oct 20, 2014 11:30:51 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class com.stod.server.Service
Oct 20, 2014 11:30:51 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
Oct 20, 2014 11:30:51 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.17.1 02/28/2013 03:28 PM'
Oct 20, 2014 11:30:56 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse write
SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class org.apache.openjpa.enhance.com$stod$models$User$pcsubclass, and Java type class com.stod.models.User, and MIME media type application/json was not found
Oct 20, 2014 11:30:56 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse write
SEVERE: The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/json ->
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General

Oct 20, 2014 11:30:56 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse logException
SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class org.apache.openjpa.enhance.com$stod$models$User$pcsubclass, and Java type class com.stod.models.User, and MIME media type application/json was not found
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:285)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1479)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class org.apache.openjpa.enhance.com$stod$models$User$pcsubclass, and Java type class com.stod.models.User, and MIME media type application/json was not found
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: You need to narrow down your code snippets and put only the relevant ones.. nobody would ready through pages of code to give an answer.

Comment: I have narrowed it down already. I can't narrow it down any further because I don't know where the error is...

Answer (score 0):

The Exception stacktrace said, that there is no MessageBodyWriter:

> javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class org.apache.openjpa.enhance.com$stod$models$User$pcsubclass, and Java type class com.stod.models.User, and MIME media type application/json was not found

and especially not for org.apache.openjpa.enhance.com$stod$models$User$pcsubclass:

> org.apache.openjpa.enhance.com$stod$models$User$pcsubclass, and Java type class com.stod.models.User, and MIME media type application/json was not found

For me, it looks like the **runtime type** of your casted User doesn't match and jersey isn't able to find the correct class to create a new instance from. (*but i'm not 100% sure so don't blame me* ;))

Make sure the User is really of the type User, if you get it back from your `lHelper.findUser(user)`. It looks like it's an openjpa proxy some-what, which is not an XMLRootElement and therefore the code will not work ...

Also **don't** mix jersey versions, it's a no go:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version> <-----------------------------
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.12</version> <-------------------------------
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then, there are much newer versions, think about upgrade jersey for you project. The currently new 2.13 works fine for me in production.

Btw, you mix XmlAccessorTypes. In my eyes it's much nicer (code-wise) to use a single type like `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` and in this case only annotate field declarations - but nvm ;)

Hope this was somehow helpfull / have a nice day.

Comment: Yeah, I think it has something to do with `pcsubclass` that gets added to a persisted entity. I checked the two cases: (1) when I return a non-persisted (non-managed) entity, the debugger shows that `pcStateManager` is `null` but when (2) I return an entity that was read off the database, `pcStateManager` is not null (and has different fields for, presumably, keeping track of the changes). I just need to figure out how to ignore this added subclass when returning the entity as a JSON...

Comment: Looks like you have to detach the object or give openjpa the order to not store pcStateManager in your entity. Have a look at [Defining the Detached Object Graph](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.1/apache-openjpa-1.0.1/docs/manual/ref_guide_remote.html#ref_guide_detach_graph)